# Python - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Entities'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I have a python project with the following structiure:

```
--ProjDir
   -driver.py
   --utils
     -dog.py
     -Entities.py
```

`driver.py` contains the following imports:

`from utils.dog import *`

`dog.py` contains the below import:

`from Entities import *`

It works fine if I initialize a python REPL in `utils` folder and run `from Entities import *`. When I launch `driver.py` on a server, I am seeing the follwoing error:

```
File "ProjDir/driver.py", line 10, in <module>
from utils.dog import *
File "/home/hadoop/ProjDir/utils/dog.py", line 8, in <module>
from Entities import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Entities'
```

I am not sure why the error is being thrown and how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`import` can take either an absolute, or a relative module path. The absolute path is searched from [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path); the relative from the module where the `import` is executed. You are trying to find `Entities` relative to `dog`, but you are using the absolute module path syntax.

Inside `dog`, either use the absolute path:

```
from utils.Entities import *
```

or use the relative path syntax:

```
from .Entities import *
```

---

As a side-note, `import *` is a bad practice, as it decreases the maintainability long-term — it is not clear which module a name is imported from, and you can accidentally shadow a name by introducing the same name in a different module. Either import explicitly what you need, or import the whole module and use it as a namespace.